# Configure Redelivery Limit- Default Message Listener Container

Tags: jms, message

I am trying to get the redelivery limitset for the weblogic jms queues that we had set up. Problem statement is I have to check the re-delivery limit and the redelivery count. If these 2 counts match then I have to do an operation X. Here is my java code.

```
if(message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount") == message.getIntProperty("Property Name???")){doX();}
```

What is the property name to get the Delivery Limit?

Is there a documentation that says what are all the properties that we can use in the getXProperty()?

For now I have set the redelivery limit as 10 in the Weblogic Console for the queue. I would like to set the delivery limit in XML.

```
<bean id="sampleDMLC" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" init-method="initialize"> <property name="??"><value>10</value></property></bean>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have modified the my question. Can you please clarify now?